# Achievements dropdown no longer listing earned badges?

Tags: bug, badges, bounties, achievements-dialog

I have just awarded my first bounty in stackoverflow and got the bronze "Benefactor" badge, but I somehow didn't got notified about this in my recent achievements dropdown. It used to do that with the other badges. That is how it looks for me, **no more badge earned notice**:

[image]

In fact I noticed the earning of the badge only because the bronze badge counter increased

For the case you say

> "It is not a bug, we removed it"

I want this back :-) I think it is actually useful to see what badge has just been earned.

Comment: The tl;dr of it being that you didn't get notified because you meet the "veteran" user criteria and that particular bronze badge isn't one of the ones such users get notified of. Whether or not that functionality is still necessary given the dramatic changes in how that stuff is reported is an interesting question.

Comment: @TimStone I am just reading it.. with 200 Rep someone is already a Veteran? That is a bit odd to me :-) I wouldn't consider myself a Veteran in stackoverflow yet, really!

Comment: Well, the idea before was that most people with over 200 reputation tend to get other badges anyway, and there was no sense in overwhelming them with "lesser" badges. But now that all of that is consolidated in that menu it's probably not as important to reduce the notifications because they aren't as obnoxious, so it might make sense to suggest removing that restriction (or otherwise change it somehow).